# Let Vue register datepicker event

Tags: javascript, uikit, vue.js, vuejs2

How can i let Vue know that the datepicker changed the date?

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    termin: ''
  },
  computed: {

  },
  methods: {

  }
})
```

Just an input field:

```
<div id="app">

  <div class="uk-form-icon"><i class="uk-icon-calendar"></i>
    <input name="termin" v-model="termin" value="" placeholder="Choose date" type="text" data-uk-datepicker="{format:'DD.MM.YYYY'}" required="required">
  </div>
<p>
Date: {{termin}}
</p>
</div>
```

If you chage the input field by hand Vue gets it, but not after triggering the picker.

https://jsfiddle.net/Honkoman/dfohvcpk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way to do this would be to add a handler for the hide event from the datepicker in your Vue.

```
mounted(){
  $(this.$el).on('hide.uk.datepicker', e => this.termin = this.$refs.date.value)
}
```

Here is your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dfohvcpk/2/) updated to do that.

However, traditionally, you should wrap jQuery interaction in a [wrapper component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html).

```
Vue.component("datepicker",{
    props:["value"],
    template:`
    <input ref="date" name="termin" :value="value" placeholder="Choose date" type="text" data-uk-datepicker="{format:'DD.MM.YYYY'}" required="required">
  `,
  mounted(){
        $(this.$el).on('hide.uk.datepicker', e => this.$emit('input', this.$refs.date.value))
  }
})
```

And your template would become

```
<div class="uk-form-icon"><i class="uk-icon-calendar"></i>
  <datepicker v-model="termin"></datepicker>
</div>
```

And here is your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dfohvcpk/3/) updated to work with that.

Comment: in both methods somehow i get `[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: $ is not a function"`. looks like jquery is not known...?

Comment: @Mike sounds like it. You need to make sure jQuery is loaded.

Comment: well it is. even before all other

Comment: @Mike Not sure what to tell you :) Can you make a working example that duplicates the error?

Comment: not really. will write an info if i find something.

Comment: OK got it. I missed the ref="date" in the input element and i didn't know this: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs

Answer (score 0):

UiKit events + Vue.set :
[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gLb28wgu/)

```
$('input[name="termin"]').on('hide.uk.datepicker', function(){
   Vue.set(vm, 'termin', document.querySelector('input[name="termin"]').value)
});
```